# How to configure truffle to connect to RSK Testnet public node?

Tags: truffle, rsk

I'm using the following configuration in truffle

```json
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    rsk_testnet: {
      host: "https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co",
      network_id: '31',
      gasPrice: 59240000, // 0.5924 Gwei
    }
  },
  solc: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: false
    },
    version: "0.5.17",
    evmVersion: 'petersburg'
  },
};
```

However I'm getting stuck with intermittent errors with network timeouts. i.e.

```
Invalid JSON RPC response: "<html>\r\n<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
    at Object.InvalidResponse (node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\webpack:\truffle-hdwallet-provider\web3\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\src\errors.js:42:1)     
    at t.InvalidResponse [as onreadystatechange] (node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\webpack:\truffle-hdwallet-provider\web3\node_modules\web3-providers-http\src\index.js:92:1)
    at t._a [as dispatchEvent] (node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\webpack:\truffle-hdwallet-provider\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:27:61)  
    at t.dispatchEvent [as _setReadyState] (node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\webpack:\truffle-hdwallet-provider\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:1)   
    at t._setReadyState [as _onHttpResponseEnd] (node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\webpack:\truffle-hdwallet-provider\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:318:1)
    at IncomingMessage._onHttpResponseEnd (node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\webpack:\truffle-hdwallet-provider\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:289:47)   
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:198:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1139:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `truffle-config.js` file:

(1) Set a variable `testnetSeedPhrase` to
contain a valid BIP-39 mnemonic phrase

(2) Set a variable `gasPriceTestnet` to
contain the gas price you wish to use denominated in Wei.

(3) In the exported `config` object,
set the value of `config.networks.testnet` to be the following.

```js
    ...
    testnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider({
        mnemonic: {
          phrase: testnetSeedPhrase,
        },
        providerOrUrl: 'https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co/',
        // Higher polling interval to check for blocks less frequently
        pollingInterval: 15e3,
      }),
      // Ref: http://developers.rsk.co/rsk/architecture/account-based/#chainid
      network_id: 31,
      gasPrice: gasPriceTestnet,
      networkCheckTimeout: 1e6,
      timeoutBlocks: 100,
      // Higher polling interval to check for blocks less frequently
      // during deployment
      deploymentPollingInterval: 15e3,
    },
    ...
```

(4) Now you can run `truffle` subcommands with this network selected,
for example:

```sh
truffle migrate --network testnet
```

Note that these options were originally not configurable in Truffle,
and were set to hard coded defaults.
These were added specifically to be able to support networks
with a different block interval!

Context:

- [adding `provider.pollingInterval`](https://twitter.com/DAppsDev/status/1324929409158012929)
- [adding `deploymentPollingInterval`](https://twitter.com/DAppsDev/status/1328695467081756673)